# Send email without server using google script: error after clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, html, email, google-apps-script, forms

I want to send an email to a location target@example.com using google script . I am following this - https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server to setup the whole functionality in my website.

There is an html form in my website and I want to send email whenever someone clicks on the submit button on my site

here is the html of the form -

```html
 <form id="gform" method="POST" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyacpl2YxzZIVDPuizRqrzedC-7mAtMywSvoVbfLbebA6MdkUKs/exec">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Your Name (required)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputEmail1" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Your Email (required)</label>
    <input type="Email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputPassword1" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Your Phone Number (required)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone-num" id="exampleInputPassword1" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="exampleInputPassword1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Message</label>
   <textarea class="message" name="message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is the script.g file which is working fine -

```js
var TO_ADDRESS = "target@example.com"; // where to send form data

function doPost(e) {

  try {
    Logger.log(e); // the Google Script version of console.log see: Class Logger
    MailApp.sendEmail(TO_ADDRESS, "Contact Form Submitted",
                      JSON.stringify(e.parameters));
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(e.parameters) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(error) { // if error return this
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}
```

I wanted to style the json object which is getting passed so when I use the following script -

```js
// if you want to store your email server-side (hidden), uncomment the next line
var TO_ADDRESS = "target@example.com";

// spit out all the keys/values from the form in HTML for email
function formatMailBody(obj, order) {
  var result = "";
  // loop over all keys in the ordered form data
  for (var idx in order) {
    var key = order[idx];
    result += "<h4 style='text-transform: capitalize; margin-bottom: 0'>" + key + "</h4><div>" + obj[key] + "</div>";
    // for every key, concatenate an `<h4 />`/`<div />` pairing of the key name and its value, 
    // and append it to the `result` string created at the start.
  }
  return result; // once the looping is done, `result` will be one long string to put in the email body
}

function doPost(e) {

  try {
    Logger.log(e); // the Google Script version of console.log see: Class Logger
    record_data(e);

    // shorter name for form data
    var mailData = e.parameters;

    // names and order of form elements
    var dataOrder = JSON.parse(e.parameters.formDataNameOrder);

    // determine recepient of the email
    // if you have your email uncommented above, it uses that `TO_ADDRESS`
    // otherwise, it defaults to the email provided by the form's data attribute
    var sendEmailTo = (typeof TO_ADDRESS !== "undefined") ? TO_ADDRESS : mailData.formGoogleSendEmail;

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: String(sendEmailTo),
      subject: "Contact form submitted",
      // replyTo: String(mailData.email), // This is optional and reliant on your form actually collecting a field named `email`
      htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData, dataOrder)
    });

    return ContentService    // return json success results
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(e.parameters) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(error) { // if error return this
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}
```

I get this error -

```js
{"result":"error","error":{"parameter":{"subject":"subj",
"name":"shan","message":"msg","email":"sh@sh","phone-num":"46546"},
"contextPath":"","contentLength":64,"queryString":"","parameters":
{"subject":["subj"],"name":["shan"],"message":["msg"],"email":["sh@sh"],
"phone-num":["46546"]},"postData":{"type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"length":64,"contents":"name=shan&email=sh%40sh&phone-num=46546&subject=subj&message=msg",
"name":"postData"}}}
```

It happens only with the second script. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: not sure it's the case, but have you tried sending to a real, existing email? Maybe the thing is that sh@sh is not at all a valid email address?

Comment: same error. There is just one check with the email field that it has this format or not (someText)@(someText). It has no checks related to validity of the mail entered.