# google script error: unexpected token: u

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script

I am using google script.
Here is the object to which I am applying .formDataNameOrder

```js
{subject=[subj], name=[shan], phoneNum=[4132145], message=[msg], email=[shan@ss]}
```

In the logs I am getting unexpected token: u

If I log the error I am getting this -

```js
"message":"Unexpected token: u","name":"SyntaxError","fileName":"script (html contact form sendEmail)","lineNumber":31,"stack":"\tat script (html contact form sendEmail):31 (doPost)\n"}
```

Where am I going wrong ?

This object is available as e.paramaters and after applying .formDataNameOrder it becomes e.parameters.formDataNameOrder

Here is a little background of the problem - [Send email without server using google script: error after clicking submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000946/send-email-without-server-using-google-script-error-after-clicking-submit-butto)

Comment: `Unexpected token: u` usually means that you’re getting `undefined` somewhere.

Comment: but the values are clearly not undefined. How can they be undefined in this example?

Comment: run the first snippet ... `"message": "SyntaxError: illegal character",` that so called object is not valid javascript syntax at all

Comment: an object is declared like `{key: value, key1: value1}`

Comment: yes it is not but this is what I get as "e" for the doPost method in google script file - {parameter={subject=subj, name=shan, phoneNum=4532165, message=msg, email=shan@ss}, contextPath=, contentLength=67, queryString=, parameters={subject=[subj], name=[shan], phoneNum=[4532165], message=[msg], email=[shan@ss]}, postData=FileUpload}

Comment: from this it should extract parameters and then formDataNameOrder as e.parameters.formDataNameOrder